# Image copy, create and rename with PHP?

Tags: php, image-manipulation

I need to create a function that, given a target folder will...

1) Check to see if a file named myImage.png exists in the target folder and creates a copy of it called myImage-default.png

2)Checks to see if a file named "myImage-trans.png" exists in the target folder (creates it if not), makes a copy of it and saves it as myImage.png (myImage-trans.png should be a 1x1 pixel transparent png)

How difficult might this be and what PHP methods would you use?

- All images will reside in the root of the target folder. No subfolders involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't be too bad.

Here are some PHP functions that will get you started:

[filexists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) - Check if that file exists

[imagecreate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) - Create an image if that image doesn't already exist

[imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) - Output a PNG file with your newly created image

[imagecopy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) - Copy a portion of an image

[copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) - Copy a file

[rename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) - rename a file

Comment: Thanks Chase. Checking them out now.

Comment: if I just want to rename an existing image (myImage.png > myImage-default.png), I suppose it be simpler just to call rename() right?

Comment: Why would you call `imagecopy` when you're only wanting to copy the file, not the actual image data?

Comment: @James Good point. If he is copying the whole image, which would've been safe to assume and my mistake, he should only have to use PHP's `copy` function. I have updated my answer as such.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at basic file system functions. Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) for a list of available functions!